# Sharepoint Migration From 2010 to 2016 only Documents

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

Hi In my sharepoint 2010 site I have 75 groups and  Nearly 3000 users. I am doing manual migration. I need to move only the document from 2010 to 2016 along with permission given to the document in 2010. Please suggest me the solution. I am new to migration. Thanks for you Help.

Comment: Are the permissions for the individual documents maintained when moved?

Comment: Yes have to be maintained